# js objects and if statements. why this code works without an else and using an else or else if statement doesn't?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am a very beginner JS "developer" (student) and I have run into a question I haven't been able to solve: why does the value of the repeated letters in my 'helperHash' increase when I am not using an else statement and why this same value DOESN't increase if I use an else statement? My code runs as expected but I am having problems understanding the logic behind this issue...

The code is supposed to return an array with the letters that have 1 or more repetitions in the given str.

```
function nonUniqueLetters(str){
  var strToChars = str.split('');
  var finalArr = [];
  var helperHash = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < strToChars.length; i += 1){
    let char = str[i];
    if (!helperHash[char]){
      helperHash[char] = 0;
    }
    helperHash[char] += 1;  //HERE! why doesn't this work if inside an else?
  }
  for (var key in helperHash){
    if (helperHash[key] > 1){
      finalArr.push(key);
    }
  }
  return finalArr;
}
```

Comment: Because if it is inside of an `else`, it will only run when the `if` condition is `false`. If that never happens, the `else` block is never hit.

Comment: helperHash[char] += 1;` won't run in an else because the opposite statement is not evaluating to `true` (i.e the opposite of `!helperHash[char]` is not evaluating to `true`...)

Check the mdn docs for FOR LOOPS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for and checkout the `break;` statement for more control over your loop

And IF STATEMENTS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: What would be _most useful_ is for you to set up a working snippet, which has a sample string that you are passing in.  Then, you share with us what it _does_ produce (which is presumably wrong), and what _you want it to produce_.

Comment: That looks correct to me as it is.  If the character doesn't exist in the object then create it with a count of 0.  The next line increments it so it becomes 1.  If you put the next line after an else then it never increments it, so `helperHash[char] == 0`, meaning `!helperHash[char] == true` so it keeps setting it to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic error.

#### How the current code works:

```
if (!helperHash[char]){
    // Enters here only when helperHash[char] is not set (or 0, but it is never 0)
    helperHash[char] = 0;
}
// Always increment
helperHash[char] += 1;
// There is no 0 in helperHash at this point
```

#### Why putting `helperHash[char] += 1` in an `else` branch doesn't work:

```
if (!helperHash[char]){
    // Enters here only when helperHash[char] is not set or 0
    helperHash[char] = 0;
    // Still 0, will take this branch again on the next occurrence of char
} else {
   // Increment only if it was already 1 or more (this never happens)
   helperHash[char] += 1;
}
// Here helperHash contains only 0 for all keys
```

#### How to make it work:

```
if (!helperHash[char]){
    // This is the first occurrence of char, let's count it
    helperHash[char] = 1;
} else {
    // This is a subsequent occurrence of char, let's count it too
    helperHash[char] += 1;
}
// There is no 0 in helperHash at this point
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I had no idea that !0 will evaluate to true hence I kept wondering about this.

Answer (score 2):

For `helperHash[char]`…

The initial value is `undefined` and `!undefined` is `true` so it sets the value to `0`.

The next time `char` has the same value, `helperHash[char]` is `0` and `!0` is **also** `true` so it sets the value to `0` (which it already is, so it makes no difference).

---

Instead of testing if the value is a false value, test if it is undefined, or if it exists at all.

```
if (typeof helperHash[char] === "undefined")
```

or

```
if (char in helperHash)
```

Comment: Was about to suggest you include the alternate (`typeof`) comparison, but you beat me to it! Type comparisons in JS can be very confusing....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this `if (!helperHash[char]){` and how integers are converted to booleans in Javascript.

You initialize every member of the hash to 0 which equals a boolean false, so the else is never hit because `helperHash[char] === 0 === false` and thus `!helperHash[char]` is true for all values initialized with 0

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition:

```
!helperHash[char]
```

is always evaluating to `true` (`helperHash` never has characters in it that are "falsy"). So, an `else` branch of that `if` would never be hit.